# Wildcard searching single text field in MySQL with PHP on HTML page

Tags: php, html, mysql, search, wildcard

I've inherited some PHP scripts from a colleague and one is used for searching the "Notes" text field of a database called "Sheep" via a text box:

[image: text search box]

Code for the search box:

```
<h2>Find sheep Notes</h2>

Please note this looks at both sheeps and lambs.

    <form method="post">
        <label for="sheep"><br>Enter text in the box</label>
        <input type="text" id="sheep" name="sheep">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="View Results">
```

However when anything is searched it currently shows the following error:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(DOB, '%d-%m-%Y') AS DOB, DATE_FORMAT(`Record started Date`, '%d-%m-%Y') AS `Record started Date`, FROM Sheep, WHERE `Notes` LIKE '%section%'
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
No results found for section.
```

I don't know PHP well at all but below is the PHP code. All I know is that it needs to be able to search the text field called "Notes" for any string of text using the wildcard syntax:

```
<?php

//error_reporting(-1);
//ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  try {
    require "./config.php";
    require "./common.php";

    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
$notes = $_POST['sheep'];
    $sql = "SELECT *,
DATE_FORMAT(DOB, '%d-%m-%Y') AS DOB,
DATE_FORMAT(`Record started Date`, '%d-%m-%Y') AS `Record started Date`
FROM Sheep
WHERE `Notes` LIKE '%$notes%'";

    $sheep = $_POST['sheep'];

    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam(':sheep', $sheep, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
  } catch(PDOException $error) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
  }
}
?>
```

Can anyone advise where this is wrong? I've done some research but after many attempts at fixing it I've not been able to.

Comment: There is no `:sheep` in your query to bind to. I'd suggest reading up on [prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) / [bindValue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

Comment: Do you really have a column in the `sheep` table called `Record started Date`?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius yes there does appear to be, why? Like I said I inherited this project so I didn't make the MySQL database.

Comment: Looks like changing `/WHERE `Notes` LIKE '%$notes%'"` to `WHERE `Notes` LIKE :sheep";` pulls all entries that have nothing in the "Notes" field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `$notes` in the query with `:sheep`. Then concatenate the wildcard characters to to `$sheep`.

```
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    $sql = "SELECT *,
DATE_FORMAT(DOB, '%d-%m-%Y') AS DOB,
DATE_FORMAT(`Record started Date`, '%d-%m-%Y') AS `Record started Date`
FROM Sheep
WHERE `Notes` LIKE :sheep";

    $sheep = '%' . $_POST['sheep']. '%';

    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam(':sheep', $sheep, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar! :) That has sorted it. I had the first part but not the second.